# How to debug/inspect hexo blog

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, hexo

I'd like to start a Nodejs debugger for my Hexo blog to understand how my theme works and possibly find a bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I needed 2 things to achieve this:

1. Install `hexo-cli` as a dev dependency rather than global. I used `npm i hexo-cli --save-dev`.
2. In `package.json`, under `scripts`, add a script called `debug`. I used this command: `node --inspect=4300 ./node_modules/hexo-cli/bin/hexo server`.

Then just use `npm run debug` and you're good to connect with a debugger to port 4300 (or whatever port you want to set in your command) and do line-to-line debugging etc.

One caveat is that with the `--inspect` setting, for some reason hexo is starting extremely slow (takes more than 2 minutes). I wonder what causes this.

Also, I haven't found a way to start hexo in a way that it generates pages dynamically. It would help with real time debugging.